# C++ preventing method overriding

Tags: c++

Is there any way in C++ by which we can declare virtual method un-overridable just like final methods in Java.

I know by making default constructor private of class I can make class final but what about just virtual method ?

Thanks

Comment: Methods aren't overridable by default. If you don't say they can be overridden, they can't.

Comment: I would respond to your example code with an explanation, but you seem to have forgotten to include your sample code.

Comment: @kfsone I'm not sure its required for this question. If you struggle with reading comprehension let me know. I'm always glad to help out vs. posting absolutely tongue and cheek comments on SO. SO a place to help, not trample.

Comment: @freddy SO has it's rules for reasons, and without code there is always a high probability of ambiguity on the posters' part. You see it as trampling, I saw it as a light-hearted assist to getting the answer he needs. See Ceros' answer, which is good, but apparently didn't hit all the unspecified marks the OP didn't disambiguate.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare your method virtual like so:

```
virtual myMethod();
```

Then they can be overriden. Remove virtual to make them "un-overidable"

Since C++11, you can also use final with virtual like so:

```
virtual myMethod() final;
```

[Final keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: Is there any way to do this in C++03

Comment: @noname By not adding `virtual`

Answer (score 1):

Starting from C++ 11, there is as well a final keyword which can be used both on classes and methods.

It's to my knowledge not possible to do this with prior versions.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicit_overrides_and_final

Answer (score 0):

Despite the fact that C++11 and later allows method to be declared `final`, I dare say it is not a good thing to do. Do not seal down your class! Users of it might have inventive scenarios, and they might need to tweak it a bit. Why deprive them of this option?

If you look into standard library implementation (one of the best sources of really good programming in terms of both efficiency and style) you will see that members are never final, nor are the classess themselves.

Comment: The class designer should have a very good reason for making anything final, but there are good and valid reasons to do it. [Obligatory link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/strange-inheritance#final-classes)

Comment: Haven't really seen any of the good reasons to make anything final.

Comment: Haven't seen it so it doesn't exist? Big businesses have engineers that disagree. Click my link.

Comment: I have read the link, it doesn tell why you need it. Efficiency has nothing to do with - you do not have to declare your members virtual and still leave them not final. Again, see STL. As for fear of 'slicing' it should not be your concern as the class author. The class itself should have properly defined copy/assignment methods, the rest is not the class author problem.

Comment: Why are you asking me to defend something industry-standard? If you want to post your obvious _opinion_, that's fine, but that doesn't negate good reasons. Finding them is as easy with Google. The C++FAQ is maintained by People Who Matter and they think that final classes have a good reason for existing. Business needs trump everything else, and plenty of businesses find a need for final classes. And your argument against slicing is not valid: slicing is an actual problem that people actually experience in actual production code with classes that have properly defined copy/assignment methods.

Answer (score 0):

How to make a final class in C++ versions before C++11:
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Final_Class